# Calculate side of a triangle with known base and median

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: triangle]

Is it possible to calculate the size *a* of the triangle where *t* is a median? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $\overline{AS}$ is a median is irrelevant here. You're asking if, given lengths $AB$ and $AS$, you can determine (uniquely) the triangle $\triangle ABS$. There are infinitely many such triangles — imagine fixing $\overline{AS}$ and drawing a circle of radius $c=8$ centered at $A$. All but two of the points on that circle can be vertex $B$.